# At what speed should a ship travel from Jupiter to Earth to reach Earth in only 3 hours?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-resurrection-1997

In *Alien Resurrection*, the science ship was parked in "unregulated space" while they did experiments. Then, when the aliens get loose, the ship starts an autopilot trip program to fly back to Earth. When Ripley asks how long until they get to Earth, a soldier says 3 hours. The next shot is of the ship passing by Jupiter on its way. The ship does not look to be traveling at the speed of light! So how fast would the ship need to travel to go from, we'll say, slightly beyond Jupiter to Earth in only 3 hours?

Comment: Maybe they slowed down on the way past?

Comment: According to Space.com, the distance between Earth and Jupiter varies between 365 million and 600 million miles. So, you're talking tens of thousands of miles per second in the best case scenario, and substantially more if you're going to factor in real world physics of deceleration at the halfway point, etc.

3 hours seems a bit unrealistic, in that light. But then again, this *is* Alien Resurrection we're talking about. :)

Comment: They are going at the speed of the plot!

Comment: Bear in mind that in the Alien universe, humanity does have ships capable of FTL travel. They may still need to cold-sleep for long journeys, but they are travelling between star systems in reasonable time frames. There's no reason to suggest that they couldn't/wouldn't use that tech within a star system as well. Although given that, I'm not sure why they would have to be going so slowly as they go past Jupiter. (nor even why they would want to go that close to Jupiter at all - it's a really deep gravity well; you don't go near it unless you actually need to)

Comment: You know what they say, in space no one can hear you scream. So they were just going at the speed of sound.

Comment: @Simba The slow going around Jupiter might be just apparent. Who knows what kinds of distortions you would get traveling FTL in a universe that allows that? Or one of the fan favourites - the closer you get to a mass, the slower you move; so going around Jupiter you'd be moving relatively slowly, and as you get out of the well, you'd move faster. This would also explain why the ship moves relatively slowly when it reaches Earth. Of course, the authors probably "just didn't care", but there's plenty of ways to rationalize it :D

Comment: The traditional sci-fi explanation for why ships don't just FTL straight into orbit (or into a spaceport on the ground for that matter) tend to be to do with how gravity wells interact with FTL drives. This is usually used to allow navel style ship to ship battles in space make sense. This sort of reasoning could easily explain 'slow' movement near a gravity well. It's going as fast as possible without FTL, but once it's out of Jupiters gravity well it can FTL to just outside the Earths gravity well and then make the final 'slow' approach to Earth.

Comment: Enlighten me, what does it look like when you travel at the speed of light? :-)

Comment: What's wrong with "Some time passed between the question being answered and when in the Solar System, the ship would slow down"? Presumably, it would be very difficult to manoeuvre at FTL over distances of the order of the Solar System.

Comment: @Maarten: I would guess it looks like you're light?

Comment: It needs to go .5 past light speed to make the Jupiter run in 12 parsecs

Comment: @Maarten the first time you hit a dust particle, it probably looks like a mushroom cloud

Answer (score 54):

Jupiter averages about 43 light-minutes from the Sun, Earth is about 8.3 light-minutes. That means, at most, it's 51.3 light-minutes from Earth to Jupiter, and at a minimum 34.7 light-minutes.

So, simple math. The ship would be traveling at between 0.193 and 0.285 c to take three hours to cover the distance, depending on the distance between Earth and Jupiter at the time.

Comment: Note that for the 0.285c computation, you're going through the Sun.

Comment: While that gives you the _average_ speed, in practive you also need to take the acceleration and deceleration (if stopping at Earth) into account, making you reach on the order of 0.5 c at maximum. Furthermore, relativity need be taken into account; if 3 hours on the ship, the time on earth would be something like 3.5 hours.

Comment: @bjorn The ship wasn't going to decelerate - it was going to smash straight into the planet. Of course, that brings up the question of how good of an idea it is to smash a ~3km long space station into a planet at .2c... :)

Comment: @Luaan thank you, I didn't know it was supposed to crash. This answer is however still wrong, in the sense that it only gives the average speed. The spacecraft must still accelerate, and, once again, relativity is not insignificant here. Check my answer below, which for some strange reason was down-voted... :s

Comment: The comments about acceleration time, etc, are not really apposite. The OP is just looking for a **ballpark understanding** of the speeds involved.  Note that - newsflash! - travel at such speeds is **100% handwaving**.  It is utterly unrealistic with any even vaguely actual-physics.  Just giving the "average speed" is all the info that is needed.  (Who knows if their drives even "accelerate"?  There may be no connection to such concepts.  There may be some other totally different concept ( "polar charge!"  "twist factor!" "beaglization!) that happens and has no connection to acceleration.

Comment: **Indeed** - note that the needed acceleration (see the other answers), is so high that it would be utterly impossible for life to exist in such acceleration.  This means that their physics *must be* some handwavey thing that plain doesn't involve acceleration.  So while it's admirable to point out that it's only an *average* speed, it's worth noting that the acceleration is simply totally impossible anyway.

Comment: This assumes a straight-line transit, which (to my understanding) is not how spacecraft usually move between planets. Of course, this does produce a neat minimum value proving it’s at least physically possible, so +1 anyway.

Comment: Did this take into consideration that the required acceleration would probably change your sense of time?  3 hours to those on the ship might not be 3 hours to an observer on earth.  Not too sure about this though.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73506/discussion-on-answer-by-keith-morrison-speed-to-travel-from-jupiter-to-earth-in). After copying them to chat, I've also deleted a bunch of comments from here; let me know if I removed anything constructive that I shouldn't have.

Comment: @Nico , but only for 2.32 seconds - that hardly matters!

Comment: @Luaan That would be quite an interesting question in itself, but I don't have time to write it properly at the moment. Obviously the damage would be above "extinction level event" but I'd quite like to know if it would liquefy the whole crust, punch a glob of mantle out the back, spray ejecta out the front, or all three.

Comment: @Nico If can go _that_ fast, I doubt that the Sun is really a big obstacle.

Comment: @Aganju how do you come to that number? 0.285c is ~85'500km/s, and the sun's radius is ~696'000km, so that would be ~16.28s, right? At ~1-10 millions K, you're in for One Hot [quarter of] Minute

Comment: @Nit well it's still a very big and very very very very heavy and very hot ball of stuff

Comment: @Nico i was lazy and believed google, as it was only meant as joke. You are right.

Comment: @Aganju oh alright, I didn't mean to point you out in any way, I just got wondering about the Sun's diameter following your comment and then your time didn't seem right, it's all :-)

Comment: @Nico Yeah, it was more in jest, a joke, if you will.

Comment: @KRyan: if you're traveling between planets within hours, your transit *is* effectively a straight line over the distances involved. Jupiter has an average orbital speed of 13.1 km/s: in three hours, that means it would have moved 141,156 km. Jupiter has a diameter of 139,822 km. So you'd pretty much just aim to where Jupiter is right now for a three hour travel time. Curved paths are when you're using orbital mechanics to go between planets, not moving at 20% light speed.

Answer (score 15):

Depends where Earth and Jupiter are in their orbits.

If Jupiter is in opposition, it is abt 390 million miles from Earth, so the ship would need to travel at 130 million mph - just under 0.2c.

If they are on opposite sides of the Sun (superior conjunction) they are a bit over 570 million miles apart, so a speed of 190 million mph would be required - just over 0.28c.

Comment: Well, if they are on opposite sides of the Sun, you'd certainly have to make a big detour!

Comment: Depends how heat resistant the ship is. The Sun's radius is less that half a million miles, so you wouldn't have to detour by much to miss it. Even if you decided that Mercury's orbital radius was your safe limit, that would be less than one-fifteenth of the distance traveled, so you'd still be going in almost a straight line.

Comment: For a ship that can handle accelerating between 0 and 0.2 c in a matter of minutes, the heat radiation you get at Mercury's orbital radius should hardly be a problem. If anything, the higher solar-wind density would.

Comment: Or indeed the higher density of just about anything. At a substantial fraction of c, hitting even a dust grain might generate enough energy to wreck the ship, unless it was built with materials unknown today. And there are a lot of dust grains floating around in interplanetary (or even interstellar) space.

Comment: What is a mile?

Comment: One 93millionth of an Astronomical Unit.

Comment: @Octopus feigned ignorance is not endearing.

Comment: @Octopus, I prefer the one they standardised to 500 meters, but it refers to a wide range of units depending on preferences, all on the order of 38 magnitudes longer than the Plank length. For astronomical purposes, as previously noted, most miles are around 8 magnitudes smaller than an AU and 13 smaller than light years and parsecs.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a nice app here for calculating exactly this kind of thing:
http://convertalot.com/relativistic_star_ship_calculator.html

First the space ship must accelerate with full power, and when it has reached half-way, it has to decelerate with full power in order to stop at earth.

What the other comments fail to take into account is relativity. Time will move slower on the spaceship than on Earth, so if it takes 3 hours on the spaceship, the time passed on earth would have been ~3 hours 10 minutes.

The acceleration would also have to be insanely high, at ~3150 g (1 g ~=9.82 m/s)

Traveling the 6.168 AU (if opposite sides of the Sun, otherwise use 4.172 AU if they are closest to each other), the following values apply:

Acceleration: 3150 g

Time on spaceship: 3 hours

Time on Earth: 3 hours 10 min

Maximum speed relative to Earth: 0.5 c (1 c = 299792458 m/s, speed of light)

Rule of thumb gives that when speed is above ~0.1 c, you need to take relativity into account.

EDIT

The above was under assumption that the spaceship will stop at Earth, but in the movie the spaceship was supposed to crash. In that case, just increase the distance, 6.168 AU, by a factor two, and adjust the acceleration such that the time on the ship becomes 6 hours. Earth would then be reached after 3 hours on the ship, and the maximum speed indicated is the speed it would impact Earth with.

Comment: Forget relativity, the acceleration would crush all humans on the ship. Possibly even pulverize them.

Comment: @einpoklum: Nonsense, the ship doesn't accelerate, the drive just shifts the universe around the ship. The forces involved are distributed among all the mass in the universe, which is basically unnoticeable.

Comment: @TMN I think you are thinking of the Farnsworth engine from Futurama now ;)

Comment: @TMN: If the ship shifts the universe around, then we can't use special relativity / Newtonian mechanics for a rule-of-thumb and the question becomes kind of meaningless .

Answer (score 6):

As has been answered by others, the average speed would have to be at least 0.2c (or 60,000 km/s) over a distance of 624,000,000 km (in round numbers). With even acceleration all the way, the end speed would have to be 0.4c, which means that the acceleration would have to be 1,154 gees. That's a pretty hefty acceleration. It gets worse if the ship accelerates to the midpoint and then decelerates. Then the speed of 0.4c would have to be reached at the midpoint, which means double the acceleration.

Comment: Better assume that they are using a spindizzy.